# Why aren't all Ruby classes affected by my modification of the Object class?

Tags: ruby

```
class Object
  alias :old_initialize :initialize
  def initialize
    old_initialize
    print "AN OBJECT WAS CREATED"
  end
end

class Test

end

test = Test.new
```

This works as expected, printing `"AN OBJECT WAS CREATED"`.

But if you use a core class like `Array`, `Hash`, or `String`, nothing happens:

```
array = Array.new
hash = Hash.new
string = String.new
```

Why is that? I had thought that they all subclassed from `Object`, so any change on it would work. But apparently it only works with my custom classes.

To make it more confusing, I realized that just as the warning said, my modification should create an infinite loop, because `"AN OBJECT WAS CREATED"` is basically creating a new `String` instance - but no loop happens. Now I'm even more confused.

Ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If subclass define their own `initialize` and don't call parent's `initialize`, `initialize` of the prarent is not executed.

For example,

```
class Base
  def initialize; print 'A created' end
end

class Sub1 < Base
  def initialize; super end
end

class Sub2 < Base
  def initialize; end
end

class Sub3 < Base
end

>> Sub1.new
A created=> #<Sub1:0x00000001429630>
>> Sub2.new
=> #<Sub2:0x000000014254e0>
>> Sub3.new
A created=> #<Sub3:0x00000001422128>
```

Comment: So in this case the custom `Object` never calls Ruby `Object`?

Comment: @limelights, I guess `Array`, `Hash` and `String` constructors does not call `Object`'s constructor. I'm downloading ruby source code ....

Comment: @limelights, [String](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e0932e3ad38a0740e65478bd85897db734980083/string.c#L960), [Array](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e0932e3ad38a0740e65478bd85897db734980083/array.c#L704), [Hash](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e0932e3ad38a0740e65478bd85897db734980083/hash.c#L431) does not call `initialize` of super class.

Comment: I see. Was this done to avoid infinite loops, or is there a darker reason? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If ruby consider really `initialize` like any other methods, then when you create a custom Object, the method lookup path is followed and the first defined `initialize` method will be taken.

```
class Base
attr_reader :foo

  def initialize
    @foo = 42
  end
end

class A < Base; end

class B < A
  def initialize
    puts "I override initialize"
  end
end

A.new.foo #=> 42
B.new.foo #=> nil
```

You can find more information on lookup path resolution [here](http://madebydna.com/all/code/2011/06/24/eigenclasses-demystified.html)